# Lost variable somewhere?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
var element = $(this);
var divName = element.parents("div:eq(0)").attr("name");
$.each(boxInfo,function(i,n) {
    if( n.boxName == divName )
    {
        var newHeight = n.boxHeight;
    }
});

clicked.parents("div:eq(0)").animate({
    height: newHeight + 'px'
}, 1000);
```

Problem being "newHeight undefined". But if I do this:

```
var element = $(this);
var divName = element.parents("div:eq(0)").attr("name");
$.each(boxInfo,function(i,n) {
    if( n.boxName == divName )
    {
        alert(n.boxHeight);
        var newHeight = n.boxHeight;
    }
});

clicked.parents("div:eq(0)").animate({
    height: newHeight + 'px'
}, 1000);
```

it returns the height. How is it that 5 lines down the variable is undefined?

Answer (score 4):

Your variable named newHeight is being declared inside of an anonymous function (the function that is passed as a parameter to `$.each`).  This means that it's value is only available within that anonymous function.  This concept is called [scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99927/oo-javascript-definitive-explanation-of-variable-scope).  It explains why your variable is undefined outside of that anonymous function.

If you changed your code to declare the variable in a broader scope, your code would behave as you expected it.  Observe:

```
var element = $(this);
var divName = element.parents("div:eq(0)").attr("name");
var newHeight;
$.each(boxInfo,function(i,n) {
    if( n.boxName == divName )
    {
        newHeight = n.boxHeight;
    }
});

clicked.parents("div:eq(0)").animate({
    height: newHeight + 'px'
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

newheight's scope is limited to the anonymous function you're applyng to each boxinfo. you need to remove the var before newheight to make it a global.

also, your code isn't as efficient as it could be since you appear to be using each() to do something that jquery could do for you  eg, `$(boxInfo).find('[boxName=' + divName + ']')`

Comment: what do you think jQuery does behind the scenes? At least with `.each` you can short-circuit the loop once you find it